# Cannot locate the wav file in the root folder of the project

Tags: c#

I have code below. It works fine. But I would like to locate the *"sound.wav"* file the folder of the project. I mean ı don't want to put it in *"D:\audio\background\sound.wav"*. I put the audio file the folder of the project but  I couldn't do that . What changes should I do in `System.Uri(@"D:\audio\background\sound.wav"))"`
Thanks.

my simple program is this. I just want to play sound.wav file from home folder.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var background = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
    background.Open(new System.Uri(@"D:\sound.wav"));                        
    background.Play();
}
```

Comment: C# projects have the concept of resources that might be useful to you.  It lets you package the sounds, images, and strings that you want to use with the binary....might want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want add your audio files in the resources properties->resources->addresource,after you done that just do this:

```
    SoundPlayer sndplayr = new SoundPlayer(YourNameSpace.Properties.Resources.TDB_Groove_04_140_BPM__RC_);
    sndplayr.Play();
    //TDB_Groove_04_140_BPM__RC_ was a file i have and added to my project just as example
```

If you prefer to place files in startup folder then:

```
var background = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
background.Open(new Uri(Application.StartupPath + @"\YourWavFile.wav"));
background.Play();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Environment.CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx) to get current working directory of your application. Then use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx) to create path to *audio* folder inside working directory:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "audio", "sound.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a directory called audio in your project you could access the file with a string like this:

```
"..\audio\sound.wav"
```

Or if your application is being run in a directory further down in your project you can use "~" to access the home directory

Comment: you mean like that background.Open(new System.Uri(@"..\audio\background\")); this does not work.